# What is the most lightweight way to check that a JSON object conforms to an expected schema?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

This is seems to be a common tedious pattern:

```
function handleResponse(httpResponseBody) {
  const body = JSON.parse(httpResponseBody);
  if (body.someField &&
      body.someField.length >= 5 &&
      body.someField[4].otherField &&
      body.someField[4].otherField.finalField) {
    /* ... do something with finalField ... */
  }
}
```

A little contrived, but the point is how to avoid boilerplate validation logic like this without resorting to full JSON schema validation for the body if you just are going to surgically access some portion of the object and want to minimally validate that that portion is structured as expected? Something lightweight, conceptually as simple as:

```
function handleResponse(httpResponseBody) {
  const body = JSON.parse(httpResponseBody);
  if (validate(body, '{ someField[>=5].otherField.finalField }') {
    /* ... safe to access body.someField[4].otherField.finalField directly ... */
  }
}
```

or possibly:

```
function handleResponse(httpResponseBody) {
  const body = JSON.parse(httpResponseBody);
  const finalField = access(body, '{ someField[4].otherField.finalField }');
  if (finalField) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

Comment: Full JSON schema seemed a little heavier-weight than I was looking for, but I see that there are simpler usage scenarios for it. But probably the try/catch approach proposed in some of the answers here is simpler still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to simply wrap it in a try/catch block:

```js
var data = {body: { someField: [0,0,0,0, { otherField: { finalField: 'test'}}]}};
try {
   var finalField = data.body.someField[4].otherField.finalField;
   console.log(finalField);
} catch(e) {
   console.error('Invalid');
}

try {
   var finalField = data.body.someField[7].otherField.finalField;
   console.log(finalField);
} catch(e) {
   console.error('Invalid');
}
```

You could also use [ES6 destructuring](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) again with a try/catch block:

```js
try {
  var { body: { someField: [,,,,{ otherField: { finalField }}] }} = {body: { someField: [0,0,0,0, { otherField: { finalField: 'test'}}]}};

  console.log(finalField);
} catch(e) {
  console.error('Invalid');
}

try {
  var { body: { someField: [,,,,{ otherField: { finalField }}] }} = {body: { someField: [0,0,0, { otherField: { finalField: 'test'}}]}};
  console.log(finalField);
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Invalid');
}
```

If you want to use a dotpath (e.g. `"body.someField.4.otherField.finalField"` you could do:

```js
var data = {body: { someField: [0,0,0,0, { otherField: { finalField: 'test'}}]}};
var finalField = 'body.someField.4.otherField.finalField'.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>o[i], data);
console.log(finalField);
try {
finalField = 'body.someField.7.otherField.finalField'.split('.').reduce((o,i)=> o[i], data);
console.log(finalField);
} catch(e) {
    console.error('Invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your design is, but if that's the expected format of the object just place your logic in a try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for future generations. Based on https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining and is available in current TypeScript and as a Babel plugin.

You could use optional chaining.

```js
const finalField = body.someField?.[4]?.otherField?.finalField;

if (finalField) {
    /* ... do something with finalField ... */
}
```